# wp_update_user_meta not updating as expected

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm having an issue importing users into a new multisite and reassigning them a customer role.

When using:

```
update_user_meta( $user->id, 'wp_2_capabilities', 'a:1:{s:8:"customer";b:1;}' );
```

the imported value ends up as

```
s:25:"a:1:{s:8:"customer";b:1;}";
```

in PhpMyAdmin.

As a result, the user is added to the multisite but has no role unless i change the value back to  *`a:1:{s:8:"customer";b:1;}`*

Any help really appreciated.

Comment: If you are getting user id than you must need to create and array and than pass that array directly in the value. it will resolved your problem.

Comment: (in case the "answer" by Stefan Tanevski gets deleted as a not-an-answer, I'll copy it here) Wordpress is automatically serializing arrays and objects, so I think that somehow wordpress is recognizing your string as an object, maybe try to unserialize it and send it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
update_user_meta( $user->id, 'wp_2_capabilities', maybe_unserialize(array('customer'=>1)) )
```

Comment: thats solved it, thank you very much. i didn't realise it would do this on an sql import!!